# Anonymous function passed to readFileSync is not returning any data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have writen simple JS object which has function `csvFileToArray`. Function should return parsed CSV array.

The problem is that I don't have output from anonymous function which is passed to `readFileSync`.

`test1` is loged to console correctly but `test2` is not.

It's my first time with node.js What am I doing wrong?

```
var passwdArray = [];
var csv = function () {
        this.csvFileToArray = function (fileName, delimiter) {
                console.log("test1");
                var fs = require('fs');
                fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
                        console.log("test2");
                        if (err)  {
                                throw err;
                        } else {
                                var csvLineArray = data.split("\n");
                                var csvArray = [];
                                csvArray['header'] = csvLineArray[0].split(delimiter);
                                csvArray['data'] = [];
                                for(var i = 1; i < csvLineArray.length; i++) {
                                        csvArray['data'].push(csvLineArray[i].split(delimiter));
                                }
                                return csvArray;
                        }
                });
        }
}

var csvHandler = new csv();

var test =csvHandler.csvFileToArray('test.csv', ',');
console.log(test);
```

Comment: your csvhandler function does not have any callbacks that's why its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **readFileSync** function and it's working sync. So you can not use callback inside it. [DOC](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options)

So you can use it like:

```
var passwdArray = [];
var csv = function () {
    this.csvFileToArray = function (fileName, delimiter) {
        console.log("test1");
        var fs = require('fs');
        var data = fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf8');
        var returnedData = doSomething(null,data);
        console.log(returnedData);
    }
};

function doSomething(err, data) {
    console.log("test2");
    if (err)  {
        throw err;
    } else {
        var csvLineArray = data.split("\n");
        var csvArray = [];
        csvArray['header'] = csvLineArray[0].split(delimiter);
        csvArray['data'] = [];
        for(var i = 1; i < csvLineArray.length; i++) {
            csvArray['data'].push(csvLineArray[i].split(delimiter));
        }
        return csvArray;
    }
};

var csvHandler = new csv();

var test =csvHandler.csvFileToArray('test.csv', ',');
console.log(test);
```

If you want to use it async you can use **readFile** function.

Answer (score 2):

Are you mixing up fs.readFileSync(path[, options]) and fs.readFile(path[, options], callback)[File System | Node.js v8.1.4 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) ?

The method you are using does not accept a callback parameter.